# Search Varchar and Integer Columns in T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a search functionality in my application which searches a string value of a particular column. The search text is passed as a parameter to the procedure. Now I have to search in another column which is an integer from another table. The input param is one but now I have to search in both the columns and return the result according to that.

//Query:

```
@SearchText VARCHAR(8000) = ''

SELECT DISTINCT Id, TransactionId, wfdFieldValue 
where (wfdFieldValue LIKE '%' + @SearchText + '%' OR @SearchText = '')
```

In the above query I have to include the TransactionId in the where condition. So that if the user searched using the TransactionId or the Fieldvalue the query will return the result.

**Note:** The TransactionId is an Integer DataType.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. You want a hit on either a substring match on `wfdFieldValue` or an exact match on `TransactionId`?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson: I need to search in both columns using a `LIKE` functionality. Not the exact one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you'll want a hit in either column to make the row show up in search results. In that case, you'll need a simple `OR`;

```
SELECT DISTINCT Id, TransactionId, wfdFieldValue 
FROM bop
WHERE @SearchText='' OR 
       wfdFieldValue LIKE '%' + @SearchText + '%' OR 
       TransactionId LIKE '%' + @SearchText + '%'
```

(You can just use `LIKE` on the integer column right away without manually converting.)

Of note though, this kind of wildcard search with a leading `%` does not use indexes in an optimal way, performance of this query will most likely not be great as the table grows.

Comment: @Sandy I think the simplest you can do for now is to add indexes on the two columns, which should allow the optimizer to do an _index scan_ instead of a _table scan_. This should work well until the amounts of data get very large. The extreme option if the amount of data is very large would be to create a search table with all suffixes added (for example, TransId 1234 would index 1234, 234, 34, 4) so that you can search without a leading wildcard, but I doubt you'll want to go there until you _really_ need to.

Comment: There may be other indexing options specific to SQL server though depending on version. You may want to consult your DBA :)

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT DISTINCT Id, TransactionId, wfdFieldValue 
where wfdFieldValue LIKE '%' + @SearchText + '%' 
OR @SearchText = '' 
OR CAST(TransactionId AS VARCHAR(50)) LIKE '%' + @SearchText + '%'
```

A cast should solve it, but I would first think about possible design improvements.